Spock Mock Not Working, Test Throws NullPointerException
I have a problem with mocking in the spock, my variabla systemTaskOptional is null, test throwing an error. Here is my code of test, and part of code with biznes logic, where is null throwing.
    def "should get system tasks and check if done - mark as success" () {
        given:
            systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndDoneFalse(_) >> getSystemTasksAll()
            userApiService.getById(_) >> UserSnapshot.builder().storeAuthorities(Set.of(StoreAuthoritySnapshot.builder().role(StoreRole.OWNER).build())).companyAuthority(CompanyAuthoritySnapshot.builder().companyId(1L).build()).build()
            systemTasksRepository.findByUserId(_) >> getSystemTasksAll()
            systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(_,_) >> Optional.of(SystemTask.builder().build())
        when:
            List<SystemTaskSnapshot> snapshots = tasksService.getSystemTasksAndCheck(1L)
        then:
            snapshots.size() == 2
            1 * systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(1L, RepositoryTasksService.SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_STORE)
            1 * systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(1L, RepositoryTasksService.SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_COMPANY)
    }

        if (notDoneSystemTasks.contains(SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_COMPANY)) {
            CompanyAuthoritySnapshot authoritySnapshot = userApiService.getById(userId).getCompanyAuthority();
            if (Objects.nonNull(authoritySnapshot) && Objects.nonNull(authoritySnapshot.getCompanyId())) {
                Optional<SystemTask> systemTaskOptional = systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(userId, SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_COMPANY); <- this is null
                systemTaskOptional.ifPresent(systemTask -> systemTask.setDone(true));
            }
        }

I define service like this:
private TasksMapper tasksMapper = Spy()
private SystemTasksRepository systemTasksRepository = Mock()
private UserApiService userApiService = Mock()

@Subject
private TasksService tasksService = new RepositoryTasksService(tasksMapper, systemTasksRepository, userApiService)

This is stacktrace:
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51363', transport: 'socket'
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/Users/developer/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/2.5.8/groovy-2.5.8.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksService.checkIfDone(RepositoryTasksService.java:53)
    at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksService.getSystemTasksAndCheck(RepositoryTasksService.java:38)
    at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksServiceSpec.should get system tasks and check if done - mark as success(RepositoryTasksServiceSpec.groovy:65)


Let me polish my magic crystal to look at stacktrace.

In my crystal ball I see you did not initialized tasksService properly.

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksService.checkIfDone(RepositoryTasksService.java:53)
at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksService.getSystemTasksAndCheck(RepositoryTasksService.java:38)
at com.nvt.pupil.tasks.service.service.RepositoryTasksServiceSpec.should get system tasks and check if done - mark as success(RepositoryTasksServiceSpec.groovy:65) this is stacktrace

private TasksMapper tasksMapper = Spy()
private SystemTasksRepository systemTasksRepository = Mock()
private UserApiService userApiService = Mock()
@Subject
private TasksService tasksService = new RepositoryTasksService(tasksMapper, systemTasksRepository, userApiService) this is how i create service


It will be easier to read if you edit it inside the question.

Done, u have now this in post

In tasksMapper = Spy() what you spying on?

Welcome to SO. If you do not mind, please provide an MCVE to dramatically increase your chances of getting a helpful answer not involving educated guesses or pure speculation quickly.

I use spy, because i want real class behavior @talex

@KarolWolny shouldn't you pass real instance to the Spy?

Im not an expert, but when im spy i do not to need mock methods in tests, but spy is not a problem

Please stop debating invisible code. SO is not a discussion forum. Whatever happens in line 53 of RepositoryTasksService, it causes the NPE, possibly due to accessing mock fields or calling mock methods returning null. But this is pure speculation. Karol, it would be so much easier for everyone with a minimal reproducer. Like this, the question is only attracting close votes.

Going out on a limb as you didn't provide the actual code where the exception happens, but I can already see that you need to Combine Mocking and Stubbing. Otherwise, your mocks will return null for those calls.
    def "should get system tasks and check if done - mark as success" () {
        given:
            systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndDoneFalse(_) >> getSystemTasksAll()
            userApiService.getById(_) >> UserSnapshot.builder().storeAuthorities(Set.of(StoreAuthoritySnapshot.builder().role(StoreRole.OWNER).build())).companyAuthority(CompanyAuthoritySnapshot.builder().companyId(1L).build()).build()
            systemTasksRepository.findByUserId(_) >> getSystemTasksAll()
        when:
            List<SystemTaskSnapshot> snapshots = tasksService.getSystemTasksAndCheck(1L)
        then:
            snapshots.size() == 2
            1 * systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(1L, RepositoryTasksService.SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_STORE) >> Optional.of(SystemTask.builder().build())
            1 * systemTasksRepository.findByUserIdAndByTaskCode(1L, RepositoryTasksService.SystemTaskTypes.CREATE_COMPANY) >> Optional.of(SystemTask.builder().build())
    }

